# Understanding proof

Tags: representation-theory

I need some help to understand some proofs which can be found in the book [Introduction to Representation Theory](http://math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf) by Pavel Etingof, Oleg Golberg, Sebastian Hensel, Tiankai Liu, Alex Schwendner, Dmitry Vaintrob, and Elena Yudovina.

- **Definition 2.6,**  I don't understand how dual representation works, I was thinking that this it's such a way similar to dual maps in linear algebra, but It doesn't look like, this definition it's the central ideal in the proof of theorem 2.6.
- **Lemma 2.8,** I don't know how I can conclude that $V_{i}/V_{i-1}$ are irreducible $\forall i$. ***My attempt***: $V_{i}/V_{i-1}=\pi^{-1}(U_{i-1})/\pi^{-1}(U_{i-2})\cong \pi^{-1}(U_{i-1}/U_{i-2})$ but I'm not able to show that isomorphism, and It doesn't have sense since $U_{i-1}/U_{i-2}\not\subseteq U$, in the same way, I was trying to use a sequence to deduce this, but I can't.
- **Proposition 2.16,** I don't know how I can conclude that $\text{End}_{A}(A)\cong\bigoplus_{i}\mathbb{M}_{n_i}(k)$ in the implication $(5)\Rightarrow (3)$ having in mind that $\text{End}_{A}(V_i)\cong k$ and no copy of $V_i$ in $A$ can be mapped to a distinct $V_j$.
- **Theorem 2.19 (Krull-Schmidt theorem),** I don't know how can I show existence of such descomposition, I tried by induction over $\dim V$ and stuck even in base step, because if $\dim V=1$ then $V$ it's irreducible, but it doesn't mean that $V$ it's indecomposable.

I'm grateful for any hint in any item.

Comment: By the way, the usual expectation is for each question to be a separate question.  Since there is a vague relationship between the questions, and because I was familiar with that text, I answered, but in the future please make sure your question is a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Definition 2.7, they use without saying that $V^*$ as a vector space is the usual dual vector space $\hom_k(V,k)$.  The definition says how this is a right $A$-module: $f\cdot a:=(v\mapsto f(a\cdot v))$.  In other words, if $\langle-,-\rangle$ is the pairing on $V^*$ and $V$, then $\langle f\cdot a,v\rangle=\langle f,a\cdot v\rangle$ gives the definition of the dual representation.  Basically, we want $\langle-,-\rangle:V^*\otimes_k V\to k$ to also be a map $V^*\otimes_A V\to k$.  (If $A$ is a group algebra, then we can use inverses for the opposite algebra, as in $\langle g^{-1}\cdot f,v\rangle=\langle f,g\cdot v\rangle$ with $g$ a group element.  By substituting $h=g^{-1}\cdot f$, we get $\langle h,v\rangle=\langle g\cdot h,g\cdot v\rangle$, meaning that the dual is such that $\langle-,-\rangle:V^*\otimes V\to k$ is an intertwiner for group algebras, with $k$ being the trivial representation.)

For Lemma 2.8, I see this as a consequence of the correspondence theorem.  Since there are no modules between $U_{i-1}$ and $U_{i}$, there are no modules between $V_{i-1}$ and $V_i$.  Thus, $V_i/V_{i-1}$ is simple (no possible kernels).

For Proposition 2.16, $\operatorname{End}_A(A)\cong ((\bigoplus_i n_iV_i)^*\otimes (\bigoplus_j n_jV_j))^A\cong \bigoplus_i\bigoplus_j (n_iV_i^*\otimes n_jV_j)^A$, where $-^A$ means $A$-invariant elements.  By Schur's lemma, $(V_i^*\otimes V_j)^A\cong \delta_{ij}k$, so by composing with the standard inclusions $V_i\to n_iV_i$ and projections $n_jV_j\to V_j$, we can get that when $i\neq j$ then $(n_iV_i^*\otimes n_jV_j)^A\cong 0$.  Hence, $\operatorname{End}_A(A)\cong\bigoplus_i (n_iV_i^*\otimes n_i V_i)^A\cong \bigoplus_i\operatorname{End}_A(n_iV_i)$.  Then, $\operatorname{End}_A(n_iV_i)$ is a matrix algebra over $\operatorname{End}_A(V_i)\cong k$ for various reasons.  A hands-on approach is to use the standard inclusions and projections to extract matrix entries from an endomorphism.

For Theorem 2.19, strong induct on dimension like so: if $V=W\oplus W'$ is a nontrivial decomposition, then since $W$ and $W'$ both have dimension less than the dimension of $V$, they decompose into indecomposables, and thus $V$ does as well.  If $V$ is indecomposable, then $V=V$ is the decomposition (every such indecomposable gives a base case).

As a point of fact, irreducible representations are indecomposable.  The $W$ above would be a non-trivial subrepresentation of $V$.